# Material2 How to open md-menu on mouseenter

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Material 2 to create a menu. I have a md-button trigger that opens a md-menu. I want the button to open on hover. I know that the Material Angular.io is still pretty new. I have googled the problem but I just come up with Angularjs results. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is a sample of my html:

```
    <button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu" class="nav-btn" ><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" id="user-icon"></i> NAME</button>
    <md-menu #userMenu="mdMenu" xPosition="before" yPosition="below" [overlapTrigger]="false">
        <button md-menu-item class="nav-dropdown" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">DASHBOARD</button>
        <button md-menu-item class="nav-dropdown">MY PROFILE</button>
        <button md-menu-item class="nav-dropdown">lOGOUT</button>
    </md-menu>
```

Comment: Your use case is not part of the Material Design Specification guidelines.

Comment: So maybe the specification needs to change. Open on hover is beautiful and reduces clicks, and doesn't get i nthe way if not used too much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by manually triggering the `openMenu()` method on mouseenter.

Example:

```
<button md-icon-button 
        [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu" 
        #menuTrigger="mdMenuTrigger" 
        (mouseenter)="menuTrigger.openMenu()"
        style="margin-right: 25px">
  <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>Menu 1
</button>

<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>dialpad</md-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button md-menu-item disabled>
    <md-icon>voicemail</md-icon>
    <span>Check voicemail</span>
  </button>
  <button md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>notifications_off</md-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</md-menu>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/2RsFsWINTJZncAeyfBXu?p=preview)

For your code, it would be:

```
<button md-button #menuTrigger="mdMenuTrigger" 
                  (mouseenter)="menuTrigger.openMenu()"
                  [mdMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu" 
                  class="nav-btn" >
  <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" id="user-icon"></i> 
  NAME
</button>
```

Comment: How would you use this to enable a developer to have multiple menus? If I can copy and paste your code twice, on hover it always enables the same menu?

Comment: The solution doesn't work well when the menu is forced to not overlap the trigger using `[overlapTrigger]="false"` attribute. In this case, the parent menu button is visible, so: 1) it loses focus on `mouse hover`, as it moves to the first sub-item; 2) it allows clicks, which re-play the opening animation

Comment: Thanks @Nehal. This works. But on the mouse out I need to close the current menu and then open up the next menu if its hovered on. Any insights on it. 

Currently on the mouse over of the first menu - opens up but I had to select any 1 menu item or click some where to dismiss the backdrop div. This spoils the actual requirement.

Comment: The link is broken @Nehal