# mat-menu pierces through "cdk overlay fog"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

This [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txgxyt?file=styles.css) (SB) shows the problem.

CSS class `.WHYYYYY` shows the "two" problems I'm facing.

1. in order for the mat-menu to open on hover I need to set `z-index:1050;` ([ref 2 hacky workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53618962/6852937)) on the menu buttons.
2. this creates a problem with the "dialog fog". (click on the button -> SB)
3. I found out the overlay has a default "z-index of 1000"

Seems I have two ways of solving this.

1. give the fog a higher z-index (hack the hack)
2. *(desired solution)* make the hover menu work with normal z-index.

   - I don't understand why I need `z-index:1050;`. It seems that when the mat-menu opens it spikes "z index-wise" very high for a moment, so that I trigger the button (mouseleave) event (that will in fact close its mat-menu again).

**Is this a bug? Can I prevent this piercing/spiking of the created mat-menu? How Can I have a working hover menu disabled under the fog?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When material cdk opens menu it creates `cdk-overlay-container` with backdrop area that fills all the browser window.

```
body
  your app elements

  div.cdk-overlay-container   - z-index = 1000
    div.cdk-overlay-backdrop
```

[image]

Once you trigger `mouseenter` event that backdrop overlaps your buttons and they gets `mouseleave` event immediately.

That's why setting z-index on buttons more then 1000 make it working.

But as you can guess you can simply throw away that `backdrop`:

**sub-menu.component.html**

```
<mat-menu ... [hasBackdrop]="false">
```

and you don't need any kind of workarounds with z-index.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txgxyt-dqm4tb?file=styles.css)**

Comment: This works! Should definitely link this to the hack workaround!

Comment: No need to add brackets: hasBackdrop="false".

Comment: @yurzui This is great, thanks! However, in the Forked Stackblitz, there is a "resetFocus" function in the template that is not implemented in the typescript (so results in an error). How should I implement the resetFocus function? thanks!

Comment: @yurzui Actually, I figured it out. I changed it to pass in the button rather than the menu and added the following code:

resetFocus(button) {
    button['_elementRef'].nativeElement.blur();
  }